# sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Hyperledger Fabric(balance-transfer example)

Tags: node.js, docker, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I'm getting errors when I make queries or invokes from Postman to my ubuntu server, which says `sendProposal - timed out after:45000`, `sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT`. I was tweaking around, but couldn't figure out what is the problem. I'm using [balance-transfer example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/balance-transfer). Running containers are the following:

```html
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
    f07e92dcdf7e        my_node/node-app             "npm start"              33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:9999->4000/tcp                           my_node
    f8b84ebc7510        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:7056->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7058->7053/tcp   peer1.org1.example.com
    301407e3285b        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp   peer0.org2.example.com
    09ef3c426af2        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:8056->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8058->7053/tcp   peer1.org2.example.com
    d46778455d1a        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
    1e14126d1920        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-..."   33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca_peerOrg1
    5bd780de76a9        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-..."   33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:8054->7054/tcp                           ca_peerOrg2
    beafd29107fa        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com


Full error log:

[2017-09-29 03:11:22.270] [DEBUG] Helper - [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: ecdsa signature:  Signature {
  r: <BN: 8afc8e33226a0f3a364ceb4c4826d3c442f26d92dda33fd7ff12027e214e354f>,
  s: <BN: 1d7ff1d66ae71f27571b5d90e95f18fbcc1c52ee8954ae03c330f22c5206333b>,
  recoveryParam: 0 }
error: [Peer.js]: sendProposal - timed out after:45000
error: [Peer.js]: sendProposal - timed out after:45000
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/src/app/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Peer.js:107:19)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/src/app/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Peer.js:107:19)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

The first container is node.js API exposed on port 4000, then dockerized and bridged with port 9999.

I read that there was a [bug](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5154) but it was solved on Hyperledger v1.0.1. How can I know what version I am using, v1.0.0 or v1.0.1?
P.S.  My Docker version 17.09.0-ce; docker-compose version 1.11.2. Node: Boron.
network-config.json ca ip address(org1, org2): My Ubuntu server ip
Other ips like Orderer and peers (requests, events): localhost

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

**UPDATE**

As suggested by Gari I made changes in network-config.json file by replacing localhost with servicenames. It looks like this:

```html
        "network-config": {
                "orderer": {
                        "url": "grpcs://orderer.example.com:7050",
                        "server-hostname": "orderer.example.com",
                        "tls_cacerts": "../artifacts/channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers$
                },
                "org1": {
                        "name": "peerOrg1",
                        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
                        "ca": "https://ca.org1.example.com:7054",
                        "peers": {
                                "peer1": {
                                        "requests": "grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051",
                                        "events": "grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7053",
                                        "server-hostname": "peer0.org1.example.com",
                                        "tls_cacerts": "../artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.ex$
                                },
                                "peer2": {
                                        "requests": "grpcs://peer1.org1.example.com:7056",
                                        "events": "grpcs://peer1.org1.example.com:7058",
                                        "server-hostname": "peer1.org1.example.com",
                                        "tls_cacerts": "../artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.ex$
                                }
                        },
                        "admin": {
                                "key": "../artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/$
                                "cert": "../artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users$
                        }
                },
                "org2": {
                        "name": "peerOrg2",
                        "mspid": "Org2MSP",
                        "ca": "https://ca.org1.example.com:8054",
                        "peers": {
                                "peer1": {
                                        "requests": "grpcs://peer0.org2.example.com:8051",
                                        "events": "grpcs://peer0.org2.example.com:8053",
                                        "server-hostname": "peer0.org2.example.com",
                                        "tls_cacerts": "../artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.ex$
                                },
                                "peer2": {
                                        "requests": "grpcs://peer1.org2.example.com:8056",
                                        "events": "grpcs://peer1.org2.example.com:8058",
                                        "server-hostname": "peer1.org2.example.com",
                                        "tls_cacerts": "../artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.ex$
                                }
                        },
                        "admin": {
                                "key": "../artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/$
                                "cert": "../artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users$
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Right now I can make first two API calls, which are successfull:

- *Login Request*
- *Create Channel request*

Getting error on the third call *Join Channel request* - `sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Connect Failed`

Full error message with previous logs:

```html
[2017-09-30 06:30:04.753] [INFO] Join-Channel - received member object for admin of the organization "org1":
[2017-09-30 06:30:04.763] [DEBUG] Helper - [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: ecdsa signature:  Signature {
  r: <BN: 14e9fb6acf44b2d9d96d5888935085bb45a2363fc3171992e73cba41c612ec93>,
  s: <BN: 1c800803823a185d0ed5a55f3a786bda1fc51827a0a296fbe432180d1e5165df>,
  recoveryParam: 1 }
info: [EventHub.js]: _connect - options {"grpc.ssl_target_name_override":"peer0.org1.example.com","grpc.default_authority":"peer0.org1.example.com"}
[2017-09-30 06:30:04.807] [DEBUG] Helper - [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: ecdsa signature:  Signature {
  r: <BN: e1cdeef11d37de28810bed04d525abf4ed4959899f64e7129483110b07d9ef50>,
  s: <BN: 65720ba0dfcdb959cce0a3d69b016097c7895aab1891172ded659aece90d467e>,
  recoveryParam: 1 }
info: [EventHub.js]: _connect - options {"grpc.ssl_target_name_override":"peer1.org1.example.com","grpc.default_authority":"peer1.org1.example.com"}
[2017-09-30 06:30:04.814] [DEBUG] Helper - [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: ecdsa signature:  Signature {
  r: <BN: e1cdeef11d37de28810bed04d525abf4ed4959899f64e7129483110b07d9ef50>,
  s: <BN: 65720ba0dfcdb959cce0a3d69b016097c7895aab1891172ded659aece90d467e>,
  recoveryParam: 1 }
[2017-09-30 06:30:04.823] [DEBUG] Helper - [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: ecdsa signature:  Signature {
  r: <BN: ac5da50d7afa8c20be3c0833f7d034761eba2f5f3051abb90c095106be273e1d>,
  s: <BN: 6815f1b1ce217faf6827521351e401f3f0accce9748ddc999de7649657024f21>,
  recoveryParam: 1 }
[2017-09-30 06:30:04.835] [DEBUG] Helper - [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: ecdsa signature:  Signature {
  r: <BN: ab6a1ea9d36c8cabc53cad8cfdf545dc0f7e7751bf43979552bb980f7fcb4b7e>,
  s: <BN: 1839adef53808d6e3ffba1f40495827cc6b4fa047d2c03dfe9ab76933581d35b>,
  recoveryParam: 1 }
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Connect Failed
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:554:15
(node:16) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of undefined
```

From the log, before the error message, I can see there is an attempt to connect: `{"grpc.ssl_target_name_override":"peer0.org1.example.com","grpc.default_authority":"peer0.org1.example.com"}`. Maybe *grpc* here should be *grpcs* since the network uses TLS. If yes, where else my configuration is wrong.. Any tips, suggestions?

Thank you!

**SOLVED!**

I solved the issue after the helpful comments from [olegabu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4686266/olegabu). I used REST API for Hyperledger fabric..

I am still getting the same error - `sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Connect Failed`  - when I am running the following requests: *join peers on the channel, Install Chaincode, Instantiate Chaincode*. Despite the error peers are still able to join the channel and channel becames available for peers. At the end I am able to invoke and query the ledger.

P.S. My upvote to the answer of olegabu can't be displayed publicly, because my reputation on stackoverflow isn't enough to do this. But I'm very grateful for his help, Thank you!

Comment: Did you start the "my_node/node-app" container by modifying the docker-compose.yaml used by the balance transfer app or did you simply start the container on its own?

Comment: I start on its own and I think that's where I'm missing the point. The way I was doing in Hyperledger v0.6 doesn't work in v1.0. Could you tell me what kind of modifications should I make in docker-compose.yaml file? Thank you for your response!

Comment: My Dockerfile:

```FROM node:boron
# Create app directory
run ["mkdir", "-p", "/usr/src/app"]
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app/
EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]```

And then in bash file _runApp.sh_ I have those two lines in order to build container and run it:

`docker build -t my_node/node-app .`
`docker run --name my_node --net=bridge -p 9999:4000 my_node/node-app`

Comment: A quick fix here might be to simply replace `--net=bridge` with `--net=artifacts_default`  (the name of the network created by docker-compose)

Comment: @GariSingh I tried your tip, but got the same error.

Comment: What about network-config.json... I only changed _ca_ ip addresses there by setting my server ip address instead of localhost. Other addresses remained localhost.

Comment: Ah - right - you definitely cannot access localhost via Docker.  If you use my suggestion, then you should be able to use the service names ( e.g. https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/balance-transfer/artifacts/docker-compose.yaml#L10 ) in the network-config.json

Comment: @GariSingh I followed your suggestion and replaced localhosts in network-config.json with servicenames. Now I'm getting the other error: `error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Connect Failed`.

 Before there was a delay while making a request and was giving the error after a timeout. But now error comes instantly.

Comment: Can you please explain in plain english ? I got this much part that "there is connectivity issue among the node (hyperledger-fabric nodes) that we started and the nodejs application taht we are starting externally" but I didn't get anything in the solution part. if you can please shed some light on it. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Is it the only way to start my NodeJS server(API server) from only the configured container? Or is there any other solution available ?

Comment: I have slight different structure I have two server one is http-server (on port 8080) to serve the static files and another one is express (nodejs) based server which exposes API (on port 8000). So I would need to expose two ports ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gio, the problem is somewhere in connectivity but I can't tell right away: in stackoverflow you mention

node.js API exposed on port 4000, then dockerized and bridged with port 9999.

could you share your repo so I can take a look?

The first I'd do is to attach to your peer dockers and see if other nodes are accessible from it, and that the cert file is available. You're using TLS (from grpcs in protocol, should I assume TLS__ENABLE is on for peers as well?) so your endpoints need to be able to see their counterpart's root cert files ("tls_cacerts" in netowork-config.js.

You may want to take a look at https://github.com/olegabu/fabric-starter This repo has scripts to deploy to one or multiple servers, has a REST API server with a debug web app. And the chaincode it uses is the balance-transfer you're experimenting with. Perhaps this repo does what you're trying to do and has solved these issues already.

Comment: Oleg, thank you. Yes, I believe it's connectivity problem. Here is my repo [link](https://github.com/pagito/balance_transfer.git).

TLS are enabled in docker-compose.yaml file by default for orderer and fabric-ca-servers, but not for peers. Should I add it like this `CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true`? Probably they will need   `CORE_PEER_TLS_CERTFILE` and `CORE_PEER_TLS_KEYFILE`. Correct?

Thank you for sharing your repo, I will take a look.

Comment: With the current repo I posted above I'm able to register/enroll user by:
 `http://serverIP:9999/users` and create the channel by: 
 `http://serverIP:9999/channels`. The next step `http://serverIP:9999/channels/mychannel/peers`, which is joining peers to the newly created channel gives me an error: `error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Connect Failed`.

Comment: I tried to add the following configuration for each peer in **docker-compose.yaml**: `- CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/ca.crt`
 
But getting the same error. The difference is that there is no timeout. So, I guess that the way is correct, just the values of cert files aren't correct.

Comment: I can't see how you start your nodejs api in a docker. When built and started from the Dockerfile in your repo it doesn't see other containers, and I don't see that you add it to docker-compose.yaml.

Comment: But instead of reinventing the wheel, add this to docker-compose.yaml:

`# fabric-rest api server                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  api.org1.example.com:
    image: maxxx1313/fabric-rest
    container_name: api.org1.example.com
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    environment:
      - ORG=org1
      - PORT=4000
    volumes:
     - ../artifacts:/usr/src/artifacts
    command: npm start`

Comment: https://github.com/pagito/balance_transfer/blob/rest-api/artifacts/docker-compose.yaml#L133

checked into rest-api branch of your repo

Comment: I start nodejs api from a [Dockerfile](https://github.com/pagito/balance_transfer/blob/master/Dockerfile). Yes, it's not in yaml file, but image is building and entering in the same network as other peers from _runApp.sh_ file.

Comment: Thank you! Working according your advice.